# Cosmos db and change feed equivalent for xml documents

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am considering Cosmos Db change feeds triggering an Azure function.  My payload is xml though not json.  Is there an analogous architecture for xml or am I required to convert to json?

Comment: You'd need to store XML in individual properties of your Cosmos DB documents (whether as one big XML "blob" or broken down into separate properties - that would be up to you). The change feed would then let you know when the document housing those storing-xml properties change. So, you'd have to figure out if that's useful to you. There's no way to store XML directly, in a native XML-specific data type, if that's what you're after...

Comment: Where are you storing these XML documents?

Comment: @GauravMantri - because that's what we are given.  not in our control

Comment: The question was "where" not "why"